# Spring 4 - Retrieve all properties

Tags: spring, properties-file

I want to return a Map of all properties used in a Spring application.  I found several questions similar to this in SO but which were relating to a specific property file whereas I wanted to get all properties.

The properties should be for the current application only - not for any other part of the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution.

<s>Note that the trickery here is of what to include or exclude.  I could have chosen to include based upon some common part of the path to a property file though in this case I chose to exclude eclipse, gradle and jre properties.</s>

I was initially excluding items but found when deployed to Tomcat I had to start excluding more items.  Instead I changed to include based on a project name (the company name is always included).  Code changed to reflect this.

This also has a small bit of Java lambda code (a bi-consumer) though if necessary that could easily be rewritten.

```
public Map<String, Object> getProperties() throws IOException {
    if (props != null) {
        return props;
    }
    props = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> includeResourcesSubstringList = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "the_company" });

    PropertiesFactoryBean propsFactory = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(
            this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    Resource[] resources = resResolver.getResources("classpath*:/**/*");
    List<Resource> filteredResources = new ArrayList<>();
    logger.debug("Exclude resources containing: " + includeResourcesSubstringList);
    for (Resource res : resources) {
        if (res.getFilename().endsWith(".properties")) {
            logger.debug("Res item to inspect: " + res.getDescription());
            boolean includeItem = false;
            for (String include : includeResourcesSubstringList) {
                if (res.getURI() != null && res.getURI().toASCIIString().contains(include)) {
                    includeItem = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (includeItem) {
                logger.debug("getProperties() - Included resource: " + res.getDescription());
                filteredResources.add(res);
            }
        }
    }
    propsFactory.setLocations(filteredResources.toArray(new Resource[0]));
    propsFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    Properties properties = propsFactory.getObject();
    properties.forEach((key, value) -> {
        props.put((String) key, value);
    });

    return props;
}
```